# Editing last blank row in a DataGridView

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview, dataset

I have a DataGridView filled from a DataSet with one blank row at the end (because of CanUserAddRows = true by default). When I fill-in some data in that row and close the DataGridView, I check HasChanges which turns out to be false and it prevents me from updating the DataSet correctly (changing data in the existing records works as expected). Debugging it showed that that DataSet has one table with only the pre-existing (non-blank) rows, so that probably is the reason it does not detect any changes (since that blank row is/was not part of the DataSet). How to solve this problem? Maybe I have to detect somehow that the focus is in a cell from that blank row and add a new record to the DataSet. Is there an automatic way to deal with it? (It looks like a pretty common situation.)

Comment: Handle the Rowchanged event and set your own flag

Comment: The change event parameter list has to be check to determine the row/column.

Comment: I'm guessing the HasChanges Event only corresponds to the changes that the DataGridView has had to preexisting Rows

Comment: does endedit() on the datagridview before the actual attempt to update help?